# am facing this problem while compiling my python code in cmd

Tags: python, django-urls

How can I remove this error?

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    return render ( request, 'users/register.html',{'form':form})
```

Comment: Can you show us what error does it give you?

Comment: can you update your question with error and froms.py file